# Adjust tikz-figure as a subfile on the text width (svjour3 template)?

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-trees, adjustwidth, sv-classes

I have to use the svjour3 document style. In my document, I need to include a fault tree which I created in a different file/chapter.
My problem: Unfortunately, the tree is not adjusted to the normal width of the document/text width (see picture)

[image]

This is my current code:

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc,circuits,calc,arrows,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.US} 
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\def\degr{${}^\circ$}

\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext  
\subfile{Chapters/extension fault tree}
\blindtext
    
\end{document}
```

I tried things like `\subfile[width=\textwitdh]{...}` but it didn't work....does anyone can help me? I would be extremely thankful! :) Cheers!

Edit:
code of the tree:

```
\documentclass[../template.tex]{subfiles}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 [
% Gates and symbols style
    and/.style={and gate US,thick,draw,fill=orange!60,rotate=90,
        anchor=east,xshift=-1mm},
    or/.style={or gate US,thick,draw,fill=blue!60,rotate=90,
        anchor=east,xshift=-1mm},
    be/.style={circle,thick,draw,fill=green!60,anchor=north,
        minimum width=0.7cm},
    tr/.style={buffer gate US,thick,draw,fill=purple!80,rotate=90,
        anchor=east,minimum width=0.8cm},
% Label style
    label distance=3mm,  every label/.style={blue},
% Event style
    event/.style={rectangle,thick,draw,fill=yellow!20,text width=2cm, text centered,font=\sffamily,anchor=north},
% Children and edges style
    edge from parent/.style={very thick,draw=black!70},
    edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) -- ++(0,-1.05cm)-| (\tikzchildnode.north)},
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=4cm,level distance=1.5cm, growth parent anchor=south,nodes=event},
    level 2/.style={sibling distance=3cm, level distance=1.5cm},
    level 3/.style={sibling distance=2.5cm, level distance=1.5cm},
    level 4/.style={sibling distance=3cm}
    ]
%% Draw events and edges
 \node (g1) [event] {Extension failure \\ E0}
        child{node (e1) {Locks \\(Le)} 
            child {node (e11) {Door Lock \\ (DL)}
                    %child {node (e111) {Door Lock \\ (E11)}}
                    %child {node (e112) {Door Lock \\ (E11)}}
                   % child {node (e113) {Shuttle Valve \\ (E11)}}
            }
            child {node (e12) {Uplock \\ (UL)}
                    %child {node (e121) {Leak \\ (E11)}}
                    %child {node (e122) {Fail to close \\ (E11)}}
                   %child {node (e123) {Shuttle Valve \\ (E11)}}
            }
        } 
        child [level distance=50mm] {node (e2) {Pressure Supply\\ (PSe)}
            child [sibling distance=8cm] {node (e21) {Main System\\ (PSMe)}
                child {node (e211) {Lose of pressure\\ (HPe1)}}
                child {node (e212) {Valve fails to open\\ (IVe)}}
                child {node (e213) {Wrong position\\ (SVe)}}
            }
            child [sibling distance=8cm] {node (e22) {Emergency System\\ (PSEe)}
                child {node (e221) {Lose of pressure\\ (HPe2)}}
                child {node (e222) {Shuttle Valves\\ (SHUV)}
                     child {node (e2221) {SHUVe1a}}
                     child {node (e2222) {SHUVe1b}}
                     child {node (e2223) {SHUVe1c}}
                     child {node (e2224) {SHUVe1d}}
                }
                child {node (e223) {Valve fails to open\\ (EVe)}}
            }    
        }
        child{node (e3) {Actuators \\(A)} 
            child {node (e31) {Door  \\ (DA)}}
            child {node (e32) {MLG \\ (RA)}}
        }
        child {node (e4) {Pipe Blockage \\ (HPe)}
        };
       
%  Remove what follows if no gates are required
   \node [or]   at (g1.south)   []  {};
   \node [or]   at (e1.south)   []  {};
   \node [and]  at (e2.south)   []  {};
   \node [or]   at (e3.south)   []  {};
   \node [be]   at (e4.south)   []  {};
   \node [tr]   at (e11.south)  []  {};
   \node [tr]   at (e12.south)  []  {};
   \node [or]   at (e21.south)  []  {};
   \node [or]   at (e22.south)  []  {};
   \node [tr]   at (e31.south)  []  {};
   \node [tr]   at (e32.south)  []  {};
   \node [be]   at (e211.south)  []  {};
   \node [be]   at (e212.south)  []  {};
   \node [be]   at (e213.south)  []  {};   
   \node [be]   at (e221.south)  []  {};
   \node [or]   at (e222.south)  []  {};
   \node [be]   at (e223.south)  []  {};
   \node [be]   at (e2221.south)  []  {};
   \node [be]   at (e2222.south)  []  {};
   \node [be]   at (e2223.south)  []  {};
   \node [be]   at (e2224.south)  []  {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    [
    tr/.style={buffer gate US,
        thick,
        draw,
        fill=purple!80,
        rotate=90,
        inner sep=0pt,
        outer sep=0pt,
        minimum width=0.8cm},
    event/.style={rectangle,
        thick,
        draw,
        fill=yellow!20,
        text width=2cm, 
        text centered,
        font=\sffamily,
        anchor=north
    },
        be/.style={circle,thick,draw,fill=green!60,anchor=north,
        minimum width=0.7cm},
        or/.style={or gate US,thick,draw,fill=blue!60,rotate=90,
        anchor=east,xshift=-1mm},
    ]
    \node (g1) [tr] {};
    \draw[line width=1pt] ($(g1.south)+(-3pt,6pt)$) --++(0.5cm,0pt) --+(0,-2cm)
    node[below,event] (b){DLe1/ULe1 \\ DAe1/Rae2};

    \node[event, left=of b] (c){DLe2/ULe2 \\ Dae2/Rae1};
    \node[event, right=of b] (d){SHUVe2 a/b/c/d};
    \draw[line width=1pt] ($(b.north)+(0pt,6pt)$) -|(c);
    \draw[line width=1pt] ($(b.north)+(0pt,6pt)$) -|(d);
    
    \node [or]   at (g1.west)   [above=of b, yshift=-0.3cm]  {};
    \node [be]   at (b.south)   []  {};
    \node [be]   at (c.south)   []  {};
    \node [be]   at (d.south)   []  {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: We haven't any information  how your images is produced. From provided image we only see, that it is to wide that can be placed on page. Try to reorganize placement of (sub)images in your image file so, that they will follows each other  vertically.

Comment: Hey Zarko! Thanks for you answer! Which information would you need? 
I was hoping to add a command to the \subfile line...isn't that possible?

Comment: You not inform us, how the image is included in your document. How, you not show to us. It seems that image  is in separate file, which is unknown to us. Apparently in this file  (sub) images is not each below other.

Comment: Ah I see - sorry! As I said I build a fault tree in a tikz-environment. The whole tree is as you said in a different document, see code above.

I was wondering whether it is possible to adjust the whole file, like the sizes of a typical figure, etc.

Comment: Please make your image file compilable.

Comment: Which image file? 
I posted all the code, there's nothing left :( Sorry, I'm really confused